# Possible impact of antimatter on space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass, curvature, antimatter

Is it possible somehow that antimatter (-ve mass) could create an upside curvature on spacetime, as it bulges outward rather than inward as in case of real matter (+ve mass)?

Comment: My answer here is relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352563/

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538078/23615 a related question with links/answers therein.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: Why do you think that antimatter has negative mass?

Comment: @SuperCiocia if you check the link I gave, there is a link to experiments at CERN checking the hypothesis that antimtter might respond to gravity with a negative sign.https://home.cern/science/experiments/aegis

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9371/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476141/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @anna v Yes but they haven't confirmed it experimentally. So far the only stress-energy tensors that give positive curvature correspond to exotic distributions of matter that have hitherto not been observed in real life. Quite the contrary, these "solutions" are usually obtained by solving the Einstein equations "the other way around", i.e. assuming a given metric solution to see which stress-energy tensor would generate it.

Answer (score 1):

Antimatter particles have mass and both produce and respond to gravity the same way as their matter counterparts. The "anti" in their name refers not to their mass but to their *electrical charge*.