# If we could weigh antimatter

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, antimatter

Imagine that we could weigh antimatter on a scale.
Would it have a negative or positive weight.
EDIT:
I see a similar question, but it dates from 2014. It mentions some experiments to be carried out. Any conclusive stuff?

Comment: This is a big unanswered question in physics, and a great one at that!

Comment: Related: [Is it possible that antimatter has positive inertial mass but negative gravitational mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589812) ... [Does antimatter curve spacetime in the opposite direction as matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83307) ... [Why would Antimatter behave differently via Gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9371) ... [Has the gravitational interaction of antimatter ever been examined experimentally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545)

Comment: Is the scale and the planet it is on made of matter or anti-matter? ;)

Comment: Well... do antimatter attract itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This experiment has not yet been completed, but physicists at CERN are [working](https://home.cern/science/experiments/aegis) on determining whether antimatter “falls” down or up under the influence of Earth’s gravity. The usual assumption is that it will fall *down*, just like ordinary matter. Finding otherwise would be a Nobel Prize-winning discovery, as it would be the first known violation of the [Equivalence Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), a foundation  of Einstein’s General Relativity.

Falling down is equivalent to having *positive* weight.