# Parity of neutral leptons

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, parity

Why we consider Hadrons as the eigenstate of parity operator? In doing so we assign each hadron a quantum no. +1 or -1. What about the parity of leptons, and more specifically parity of neutrino? The whole thing boils down to asking what will be the parity of
                $$\pi^{-}+e^{+}+\nu_{e}.$$

Comment: Can't you look that up in a table in Wikipedia?

Comment: I do not get parity of neutrino.The above reaction I think may not have definite parity.To clear my doubt i have just asked.

Comment: I believe neutrinos have the same parity as the leptons.

Answer (score 1):

A question whose answer would only moot the *real answer* to the real question underlying it.

The strong interactions preserve parity, so it is a good quantum number for the strong interaction of hadrons; and charge leptons, when considering their electromagnetic interactions, also preserving parity.

While the parity of the pion and the [electron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105370/what-parity-has-an-electron) are  well defined, it would be self-defeating, and confusing, to insist on a parity for neutrinos, as you'd be unlikely to use it.

The reason is neutrinos *only* interact weakly (and gravitationally, irrelevant here) and the weak interactions violate parity (maximally in the charged current sector!), in sharp contrast to the strong and electromagnetic ones; and so ***parity would not be a good quantum number in everything involving neutrinos***.

I cannot fathom the context of the collection of particles you proffer, but you are effectively asking for the parity of $W^+ \pi^-$, which should be ringing alarm bells.

Comment: CPT parity is conserved in weak interactions, and is the product of C-, P- and T-parities. So I think it is useful for neutrinos.

Comment: @Yodo . CPT is conserved for *everything* to the best of our knowledge, but, for neutrinos, virtually impossible to check, so hardly useful. What, exactly, do you have in mind?

Comment: Well I wanted to check if CPT parity is conserved in the hypothetical decay 3n -> 3v (decay into antineutrinos), where B-L is conserved.

Comment: Checking T for a rarest (unobserved) decay?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate T-parity either :P Is it calculable by hand? (and should we move this conversation somewhere else?)

Comment: Only in a new question. It is considered bad form to colonize others....