How do we assign definite parity to quarks and leptons when we consider them as Dirac spinors?
So as I understand it, under a parity transformation $\psi(x,t) \rightarrow \gamma^{0}\psi(-x,t)$. This to me then is not an eigenspinor of the parity operator - so how do we assign it a definite parity?
I was reading Griffiths' Introduction to Elementary Particles, and question 4.35 asks

Is the neutrino an eigenstate of parity? If so, what is its intrinsic parity?

The solution manual says that the answer is "No, because a parity transformation would convert a left handed neutrino into a right handed one (in the massless limit) which does not even exist".
I can kind of see the reasoning as being, "the neutrino possesses no right handed counterpart, and so cannot be put into a Dirac spinor which could be a pairity eigenstate", but this still doesn't answer my general question about assigning parity, and I'm not sure my reasoning for the neutrinos is right either.

I think the solution manual answer is glib: it is not unlikely that Dirac neutrinos exist, but parity is violated in their weak interactions, so there is no point in considering parity eigenstates, just as there is no point in considering charged lepton (e.g. electron) parity eigenstates--check your PDG! For quarks, however, in hadronics, and baryons, if you are mostly interested in (parity preserving) axial-anomaly-free QCD, it does make sense to consider parity eigenstates, assigned to have eigenvalue +1, as per your PDG.

Firstly if a theory violates parity, why does this mean you can't have parity eigenstates at all? Or are you saying they just won't be useful even if you construct them? For electrons, this answer : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105370/what-parity-has-an-electron seems to suggest that we do assign definite parity to electrons  and anti-electrons. If we consider pure QED, parity should be conserved and we should again be able to speak of parity eigenstates. So what do these actually look like? Even for quarks, what exactly are the parity eigenspinors given how $\psi$ changes?

They wouldn't be useful if constructed. A Dirac spinor is the sum of a left-chiral and right-chiral spinor, even under parity.

Right, so the dirac spinor for a massive electron $e = (e_L, e_R) \rightarrow \gamma^{0}(e_L, e_R)$ under parity - how is this an eigenspinor of parity? The spinor has clearly changed, so how do we assign it a definite parity?

Linked.

Thanks for the link, I did consult this earlier, but this only makes clear how the parity operator acts on a Dirac spinor. I have not been able to find a resource or link that discusses the construction of EIGENSPINORS of parity.

Try the discussion of Ch 3-4 of Sakurai's classic Advanced Quantum Mechanics. A Dirac spinor is $\psi= \psi_L+\psi_R$.

In your conventions, as I understand them, parity sends $\psi(x,t)+ \gamma^0\psi(-x,t)$ to itself. Is this at the root of your question, or whether preservation of parity is related to definitions??

I shall take a closer look at Sakurai for sure (I went through the bit on parity now but couldn't find anything immediately relevant). Yes according to my conventions, the linear combination $\psi(x,t) + \gamma^{0}\psi(-x,t)$ should go to itself under a parity transformation and is hence a valid eigenspinor - so is what we define to be the "parity eigenstate" of say a quark or an electron? Basically, when we assign definite parity to particles, I assume we should be able to write down a proper parity eigenspinor. I just want to know what that is.
